# How can I keep Classic Shell start menu in Windows 8.1 for every reboot?

Tags: shell, windows-8.1, start-menu

I have Classic Shell installed, but Windows 8.1 installed its own Start Menu. It really sucks. I tried to use it, but I miss the list of most recently used apps, just typing to find the program I want (or Control Panel item), and the compact list of installed apps.

Now, every time I reboot, the Windows 8.1 start menu appears, even though I have Classic Shell set to "Replace Start Button" selected. Before 8.1, in 8, it worked well. Now it won't keep the Start Menu. How can I get Classic Shell to start? I have to open Explorer, navigate to \Program Files\ClassicShell\ClassicShellSettings.exe to get it back each time.

[image]

Comment: Have you posted on the Classic Shell forums?  You might catch the eye of one of the authors who might have insight to how to prevent this behavior.  I assume you have installed it using "run as administrator" incase its a permission problem?

Comment: Windows 8.1 is new; give the CS devs a little time to catch up with all the little nuances. Make sure to [keep an eye out for updates](http://www.classicshell.net/history/) and it will probably be fixed soon enough (of course, update to the latest version if you haven’t already; they are regularly fixing things). Also, you can [post a bug-report](http://www.classicshell.net/forum/viewforum.php?f=12&sid=24481c804895e7765326a9d812fcaadb), but it looks like they already [know of some problems with 8.1](http://www.classicshell.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=1587).

Comment: @Synetech - As you point out the behavior described is either suppose to happen or its likely a known issue.  Hard to say to be honest. Its also possible its simply a permission problem ( i.e. run as administrator ) would solve the problem.  Other alternatives don't actually have this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem.  You need to re-install Classic Shell and select the 'Repair' option

Comment: I think this is what I did. Didn't do Repair though, just re-installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you upgraded in-place to Windows 8.1 from Windows 8, you need to do a Repair installation of the same version of Classic Shell that you have or install a newer version.

If the Start Menu does not start automatically at startup after doing this, then place a shortcut to C:\Program Files\Classic Shell\ClassicStartMenu.exe in your startup folder at C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup